# Uninstalling Python Completely from Windows

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I want to uninstall python completely from my computer. However, when I run the "python --version" command on git bash, I get the output indicating that I have python version 3.10.12 installed on my computer.

I've uninstalled python in the control panel, ensured there is nothing in the path in environment variables to do with python, and deleted the folder in appdata having to do with python. None of it is changing anything.

Resolved: The reason python was not in my system variables was because it was in the bin folder in mingw, and didn't have any keywords containing python.

Answer (score 0):

The `python --version` reply with the version of python that is pointed in your environment variables.

You should open the System Properties (you can use Windows key + Pause/Break to open it), go to the "Advanced" tab, and click on the "Environment Variables" button.

In the "System variables" section, look for the "Path" variable and select it, Click "Edit" and search all the entries in the "Path" variable related to Python. These entries typically look like C:\Python{version}\ or %PYTHONPATH%.

Before removing them, go and delete the folder at the given paths; then remove the entries.

Finally, restart your pc.

Along with the things you've already done, this should completely remove python from the system.